# How to iterate over json response without using jsx in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react and I've some doubts about how to iterate over a json response without using jsx cause I'm only able to use react adding it with scripts tag in the html file. Also Babel it's not an option.

I found this https://babeljs.io to convert jsx to createElement but it didn't work eather

This is my json response:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userId": 1,
        "fullName": "xxxxx",
        "ldapId": "xxxx",
        "contraseña": "xxxxxx!",
        "email": "c@mail",
        "deleteFlag": "N ",
        "access": "Y ",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": 2,
                "roleName": "Admin",
                "focusAccount": "N ",
                "channelAccount": "N ",
                "menuHome": null
            },
            {
                "roleId": 1,
                "roleName": "Dashboard",
                "focusAccount": "N ",
                "channelAccount": "N ",
                "menuHome": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Reactjs code:

```
class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard?user=' + localStorage.getItem("user"))
      .then(res => {
        const user = res.data;
        this.setState({ user });
      })
  }

  React.createElement("ul", null, (void 0).state.user.map(function (user) {
  return React.createElement("li", null, user.fullName);
  }))

}

ReactDOM.render(User, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In this case I suppose even if I'm doing a map over user, and I know that user it's just one, It should create one li tag inside the ul tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case you are trying to map into an object which `user` is an object. If you want to operate as an array you can use. Array.from or `[ state.user ].map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just asking about the iteration over json, it's quite simple, I found that you have object and you are using map to iterate, so you need little changes then it will work.

> I'm answering only for iteration and using `Object.keys` you can iterate inside of json also.

```
class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard?user=' + localStorage.getItem("user"))
        .then(res => {
            const user = res.data;
            this.setState({ user });
        })
    }

    render () {
        const {user} = this.state
        return React.createElement("ul", null, Object.keys(user).map( data => ( 
            React.createElement("li", null, user[data].fullName)
        )))
    }
}

export default User
```

Comment: Nice answer thanks! One more thing, I'm trying to render this with ReactDOM.render( User, document.getElementById('root')); where root is the id of a empty div tag, but this is no working, ideas? I edited the js file.

Comment: You can try this @CarolinaPonce
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(User, {}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been expending hours trying to resolve this!